# Encrypting SAP connector credentials in Web Config

Tags: .net, encryption, web-config, app-config, sap-dotnet-connector

Following is the destination configuration to connect to a server in my Web.Config.
My problem is that the user credentials are there in plain text.

```
<configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
          <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
            <section name="DestinationConfiguration" type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>
          <add NAME="ABC" USER="XYZ" PASSWD="!@#" CLIENT="123" GROUP="PUBLIC"
             LANG="EN" ASHOST="SERVER" SYSNR="00" MAX_POOL_SIZE="10" SYSID="RFC"
             POOL_SIZE="10" IDLE_TIMEOUT="10" />
        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
</SAP.Middleware.Connector>
```

Following were the options I considered.
 1. Encrypting sections - Did not work for these kind of sections as I am defining it in section group. If it is possible please suggest.
 2. Fetching from the encrypted credentials from the database. - We are reluctant to use Database as it is time consuming process for us to do schema changes.

Please suggest a solution.